# New logcat in Android Studio: show debug only

Tags: android, android-studio

I like the new Logcat since AS Dolphin. The filter adds some new possibilities, but I can't figure out one thing: is there a way to show the debug messages only without having info or warning as well?

Answer (score 8):

### You can press `ctrl + space` to show filter list

like below

[image: android-studio logcat filter bar]

So you can select minimum level, like:

```
 level:error
```

or exclude some like

```
 level:info -message:foobar
```

thats mean: all logs `who >= info` **AND** `msg not contains "foobar"`

```
 level:warn (message:ssl | -message:beta)
```

mean all logs `who >= warn` **AND** `msg contains "ssl"` **OR** `msg not contains "beta"`

Answer (score 7):

You can type `level:levelYouWant` for example `level:info` for info logs only

> level:[VERBOSE | INFO | ASSERT | DEBUG | WARN | ERROR]

Comment: That's my problem, when I type `level:debug` I still see info and warning, I wan't to see debug only

Comment: [According to Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240119623), `level:debug` means "show messages with level >= DEBUG", which effectively means "show everything". They do not plan to provide anything like "show only DEBUG level".

Comment: "there doesn't seem to be a legitimate use case for restricting the log to exactly one level." typical Google... "we know what's better so we will adamantly *only* do this and try to convince you this is _the best and only way_." I guess not much has changed other than fancy colored formatting and a few checkboxes...

Comment: `level:debug` shows logs based on the log severity level. Meaning it will show FATAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO logs too. I use `tag:foo` to filter out further.

Answer (score 4):

This is **NOT** totally correct answer
But you can write only first letter + colon character
Like `D:` will just show **Debug** logs

---

```
V: Verbose
D: Debug
I: Info
W: Warning
E: Error
F: Fatal
S: Silent
```

Comment: For me, this way it still shows Warning, Verbose and Info. It's not showing just Debug.