# Android Studio Dolphin Filter with Verbose, Info, Debug, Warn and Error in Logcat

Tags: android, logcat, android-studio-dolphin

How to filter logs on basis of different filter sections like Error, and Debug as we did before Android Studio Dolphin logcat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New logcat in Android Studio: show debug only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73944471/new-logcat-in-android-studio-show-debug-only)

Answer (score 48):

In Android Studio Dolphin, we have to search via key-value pairs in logcat. For errors, we have to write **level: error**

[image]

Comment: Dear Android Team, This UX sucks.

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/logcat-in-dolphin-version-1ae7f5f687f4

Comment: Is there any way we can do it without typing level: error like in earlier version?